# Why am I getting this '#########' as output in the fields of a column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am using ORACLE SQL* PLUS XE 11g. I made a Vehicles table with:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (
    vehicle_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    v_type VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    v_price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
);
```

And added data with:

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO Vehicles VALUES (1, 'Car', 'Limousine', 67113480)
    INTO Vehicles VALUES (2, 'Car', 'Toyota Camry', 19000000)
```

Note: Original code consists of many columns

Now to print data in this table on terminal, I used

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicles;
```

This printed the table in a unordered format. I hope you know what I mean.
Something like this:

[image]

To solve this issue, I used `COLUMN vehicle_id FORMAT A5` (To shrink the size of column while displaying). This specific command caused the output to turn out like this for the column I formatted.

[image]

I tried to fix this issue by again using this query
`COLUMN vehicle_id FORMAT A50`(To expand the size of column while displaying) but nothing changes and I still have the same output. Do anyone knows how do I solve this?

Comment: Is it oracle or is it sql-server? in your tags you have them both.

Comment: SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: Sorry but the SQL you've shared and the output screenshots do not have anything in common  I mean, how can you insert 4 columns in a table with 3 columns and get 7 columns back?

Comment: "This printed the table in a unordered format. I hope you know what I mean." I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I thought it would be bad to upload the whole statement

Comment: I mean the explanation of the problem is quiet clear and does not depend on data entered, because before I used ```COLUMN vehicle_id FORMAT A5``` everything worked fine

Comment: @Marc with due respect you can see the image. Anyway thanks for your time guys!

Comment: It's alright, I overlooked the SQL*Plus tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vehicle_id` column is numeric, so you should use a numeric column model like `99999` rather than a string model like `A5`. But the column will still be displayed using the width of the column heading, so you can change that too, e.g.:

```
COLUMN vehicle_id FORMAT 99999 HEADING V_ID
```

However, that will still be six characters wide, not five, because it allows an extra digit for a possible minus sign. You may know the value won't ever be negative, but SQL*Plus doesn't.

The behaviour you are seeing is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/COLUMN.html):

> If a number format model does not contain the MI, S or PR format elements, negative return values automatically contain a leading negative sign and positive values automatically contain a leading space.
> ...
> SQL*Plus formats NUMBER data right-justified. A NUMBER column's width equals the width of the heading or the width of the FORMAT plus one space for the sign, whichever is greater.
> ...
> If a value cannot fit in the column, SQL*Plus displays pound signs (#) instead of the number.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks, I am currently studying and couldn't figure out what was wrong. Once again thank you for your time!